# Отправить изображение для img src

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Надо "задать" изображение для тега img через запрос.
Есть разметка `<img src="http://localhost/1.php?foo=bar" width="100">`, и браузер делает запрос по этому url, но у меня никак не выходит правильно передать изображение.
Пробовал через `file_get_contens` и `imagejpeg`.

**UPD1**
это с `imagejpeg`

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng("1.png"); 
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

`file_get_contens`:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('1.png'));
file_get_contents("1.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте заголовки в файле 1.php чтобы сообщить о типе файла, который вы передаете

```
   header('Content-Length: ...);
   header('Content-Type: ...);
```

подробнее здесь, [из Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%EF%E8%F1%EE%EA_%E7%E0%E3%EE%EB%EE%E2%EA%EE%E2_HTTP)

Comment: я устанавливал заголовки, и все равно

Comment: вы все верно передаете в первом коде (UPD1). Зачем вам file_get_contents, он читает файл в строку, вам же нужно его показать пользователю на странице.